# What are suitable indoor storage options for wood

Tags: technique, lumber, storage, organization

What are some suitable storage options for wood indoors. Specifically for wood planks ranging 8 - 10 feet long by 10 - 18 inches wide. The thickness is anywhere from 1 - 2 inches. I am looking for some options that will not take up a lot of space but also will not just result in an unorganized pile of wood. I have a utility closet in my garage that is roughly 10' wide x 12' deep and about 10 feet high.

I am planning on making my own lumber in the future with trees from my land so I would need to be able to hold more than 20 planks.

EDIT: The walls/ceiling are finished but I would be ok with drilling into the walls and using studs if the storage option requires it.

Comment: It is a finished area with drywall on the walls and ceiling. I'm having a tough time picturing what you are describing. Any schematics/pictures?

Comment: Picture something like https://www.google.com/search?q=ceiling+storage+rack (which you could purchase or build custom) or a not awful version of the storage loft on http://www.askthebuilder.com/a-storage-loft-in-a-garage/ (sorry not much search capability on phone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the images I just posted to [another Question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/is-it-better-to-store-wood-vertically-or-horizontally) apply here too:

[image: Lumber racks 1]

[image: Lumber racks 2]

Comment: That top left one, is it free-standing?

Comment: @JasonC, yes. You can't see it from the one image but it's a foldable rack, with a hinge at the inside corner. From ShopNotes #109 if it's of any help.

Answer (score 2):

Heavy shelf brackets, with the lumber forming its own shelves. There are versions of this marketed specifically for lumber storage; I have one such system.

The board you want still winds up being in the middle of the pile, but with five separately supported piles it's a lot easier to reach.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the commercial version you have similar to [this](http://www.amazon.com/Storage-Portamate-PBR-001-Six-Level-Organizer/dp/B004DGIZMW) lumber storage rack?

Comment: That's one of several I looked at, that all looked about equally promising.  Which I actually bought was really determined by which one went on sale first; it was this design but marked down to about US$37.